# Meanwell LDH-45 LEDs Glowing When Controller is Off

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current

I'm using a Meanwell [LDH-45B-350](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/LDH-45/LDH-45-spec.pdf) Dali driver for currently 4 Bridgelux [BXRE-30G0800-D-73](https://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/Bridgelux%20DS104%20V8%20Gen%207%20Array%20Data%20Sheet%2020171213%20Rev%20D.pdf) LEDs with forward voltage of 18v at 350mA. The problem is when I switch off the driver, the LEDs still glow a little bit.

I saw in the datasheet today this paragraph in really bad English:

> 3. At dim off,LDH output  voltage  will  drop  to  the  same  level  as  input  voltage.To  get  luminaires  complete  dark, A please make luminaires  are  light  off  when  they  are  driving  by  the  input  voltage.

The driver is fed by 24V, does this mean that with these LEDs there is no solution for this problem?

I got the B version and 24v supply because it can drive my 7 LEDs together. The A version can only drive 4.

Comment: "The problem is when I switch off the driver, the LEDs still glow a little bit." How do you switch off the driver?

Comment: Through DALI off command or brightness 0. If I lower the input voltage to 20V the LEDs go off. My power supply's aren't adjustable to 20v though. I'm not sure if there are din rail psu's for around 18-20v.

Comment: It's a boost converter, so there is no good solution here. You need higher Vf of your LEDs, for example by using more of them in series or cheat with a diode but that will cost you efficiency. Can you just live with them glowing?

Comment: I am now using 4 LEDs in series. When complete it will be 7, will that be better? Also, j just replaced the PSU with a bench lab PSU at also 24v. This has stopped the glowing. So it is also related to the PSU. I have meanwell SDR 24vpsu's incoming. I hope these will do the trick then.

Comment: Yes, seven in series should minimize or eliminate this issue for you. Try it! Oh! And at 24 V in and 18 V Vf, you are violating the specifications from the start.

Comment: Why am i violating specs from the start ?
Input voltage is 24V and driver input range is 18-32VDC, i have 5 Leds's, so 5x 18Vf = 90V, which is within the output range of the driver (36-126VDC) .

Am i missing something?

Comment: Whut? 5 LED _modules_ with 5 LEDs each?

Comment: Where did I say 5 modules with 5 LEDs each? Each power led has a vf of 18v.

Comment: Do you have a make and model for it?

Comment: It's a standard downlight but I do took one part to see what was in them. It contains bridgelux BXRE-30G0800-D-73 led's. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.bridgelux.com/sites/default/files/resource_media/Bridgelux%2520DS104%2520V8%2520Gen%25207%2520Array%2520Data%2520Sheet%252020171213%2520Rev%2520D.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZjor9menlAhVO2KQKHXwDDcsQFjABegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw04dmCntfXxvslulbP-9nwj&cshid=1573717438361 the lighting manufacturer said 18vf, bit the datasheet of the led actually said 17.3vf

Comment: It's very strange, that you put 4 diodes in series with Vf=18V, what would mean 72V, and it still glows with a PSU of 24V, makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of that statement is pretty clear, the **minimum** output voltage is the input voltage.

So to get less minimum brightness you can either use **more LEDs in serie**s or **lower the input voltage** (or both). Too few LEDs and they might be damaged.

The topology probably looks like this (from Wikipedia commons):

[image]

For minimum output, the switch is always open so the inductor and diode are in series to the output. It's possible the diode is actually another switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw in a zener to take up the additional voltage, but it should be as low leakage as you can get.  You'd be surprised how little current it takes to visibly light some LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems solved by replacing the cheap temporary chinese 24vdc power supply.
I now have a meanwell sdr-120-24 powering the LDH module and all led's are completely off!

Comment: Sounds like the upstream power supply has bad low-load regulation or requires a minimum load for regulation and was rising high enough to start conducting through the boost supply's diode. Do you have a multimeter to check the cheap power supply's output voltage with no load?